# My datepicker's calendar opens behind the Card component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using a `Shamsi Calendar` and it goes behind the `<Card>` i used in `Material UI`, i tried setting the `z-index` of the Calendar, and also putting the whole thing inside a `div` and then giving it another z-index and of course giving them both a `relative position`, but still no luck!
Here is a minimal sample of what i just explained:
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-meadow-ergj0?fontsize=14
As you can see after you click on the `DatePicker`, it goes behind the second `Card`.
I feel like this is something `Material UI` related, specially because the `Calendar` component is kinda used by many others and it shouldn't have such an obvious bug, maybe i am missing something when giving the styles to the component ? and i have to change my approach when i work with `Material UI`?

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is due to Material-UI's `Card` having CSS of `overflow: hidden`. Since the date picker is being displayed within the card, it gets cut off at the card's bottom edge.

In this [modified version of your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/datepicker-in-card-he4lr), I have set `overflow` to `visible`. This makes the date picker visible, but has some side effects on the Card that may be undesirable.

This is primarily an issue with this date picker. It would behave in a more robust manner if it rendered the popup portion using a [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) rather than rendering it immediately after the date input. It would then leverage the position of the date input to set the popup's position. This is, however, more complicated to implement than how it works now, but would get rid of side effects on the date popup caused by the styling of the date input's container.

Comment: I sent a message to the components creator and asked him to port the component to `Portal`, as you said after reading the Portal documentation it seems just the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be from the package css itself. Try changing the position in .Calendar from relative to fixed.

Make a copy of the CSS to your src file and import it instead of importing it from the package, then modify the following:

```
.Calendar {

  --cl-color-black: #444444;
  --cl-color-disabled: #d4d4d4;
  --cl-color-error: #ff2929;
  --animation-duration: 0.4s;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1em 4em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  border-radius: 1em;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  padding-top: 3.2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 33em;
  max-width: 90vw;
  min-height: 36.7em;

}
```

to

```
.Calendar {
...
  position: fixed;
...
}
```

in the react-persian-calendar-date-picker/lib/DatePicker.css file of the package.

As for the left part that is not shown, this is because the button is supposed to be in the center of the datepicker. You could move the whole component or you could remove the margin and transform from .datepicker style.

```
.DatePicker__calendarContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 2em);
  /* left: 50%;                           Comment these out
  transform: translateX(-50%); */         /*Comment these out*/
}
```

Comment: This is the result of what you suggested: [After your edit](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-diffie-m7bzq?fontsize=14) , although this does make you see all the calendar, it does not float over the other elements and it breaks the page and the panel(Card) and obviously this is not how a date picker and its calendar should behave

Comment: Sorry I did not test the change. Here is a hopefully working change. I updated the answer.

Comment: yes it is, you can move it with transform. but since the date picker uses javascript to open and close, using `position: fixed` can cause problems when clicking on the datepicker. I think that you should consider using another module, or try to extract and modify the javascript from the module to create your own component.

Comment: [Functionality Breaks](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-franklin-qcde4?fontsize=14), After changing the position to fixed it seems it does fix the "being behind the Card problem" but it will break the functionality